# error creating ros_lib with groovy

Tags: ros, arduino, ros-groovy, ros-lib

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm not able to create the arduino library with groovy on either the Raspberry Pi or Ubuntu 12.04.  When I switched to Hydro on Ubuntu I was able to create the library and plan to copy it over, but I'm not sure if there will be incompatibilities to try and use the hydro ros_lib while running groovy.

```
pi@raspbian ~/Arduino/libraries $ rosrun rosserial_arduino make_libraries.py .  
Exporting to .
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/ros/groovy/share/rosserial_arduino/make_libraries.py", line 88, in <module>
    rosserial_client_copy_files(rospack, rosserial_arduino_dir+"/src/ros_lib/")
  File "/opt/ros/groovy/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rosserial_client/make_library.py", line 580, in rosserial_client_copy_files
    shutil.copy(mydir+"/src/ros_lib/"+f, path+f)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 119, in copy
    copyfile(src, dst)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 83, in copyfile
    with open(dst, 'wb') as fdst:
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/opt/ros/groovy/share/rosserial_arduino/src/ros_lib/ros/duration.h'
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/110556/error-creating-ros_lib-with-groovy/) by [getSurreal](https://answers.ros.org/users/9951/getsurreal/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2013-12-15

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,
in http://wiki.ros.org/rosserial_arduino/Tutorials/Arduino%20IDE%20Setup
follows the steps "3.2 Installing from Source onto the ROS workstation" and "3.3 Install ros_lib into the Arduino Environment" when you install rosserial on the raspberry pi.

Instalation from binaries is broken ("3.1 Installing Binaries on the ROS workstation").
This is due to https://github.com/ros-drivers/rosserial/issues/79 and have been fixed on sources but not in the raspbian build farm.

This works with rosserial/groovy/raspbian

---

Originally posted by [David Galdeano](https://answers.ros.org/users/9481/david-galdeano/) with karma: 357 on 2013-12-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [getSurreal](https://answers.ros.org/users/9951/getsurreal/) on 2013-12-17**:
Thank you for the response.  It worked as you described.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You must create a sketchbook/libraries folder in your home folder.
The rosrun rosserial_arduino make_libraries.py can be then executed to create ros_lib directory.

---

Originally posted by [David Galdeano](https://answers.ros.org/users/9481/david-galdeano/) with karma: 357 on 2014-01-13

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [4LV4R0](https://answers.ros.org/users/7366/4lv4r0/) on 2014-01-14**:
Thanks you so much